# OutOfMemoryError on compiling flex project

Tags: apache-flex, ant, build

I am getting OOM while compiling flex project in windows 7

```
 [java] Loading configuration file E:\work\3.4.0\frameworks\flex-config.xml
 [java] Error: Java heap space
 [java] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 [java]     at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:99)
 [java]     at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:393)
```

Settings:

RAM - 4GB
JVM Arguments - -Xms512M -Xmx1024M

Any help much appreciated

Comment: add the line of ant that actually builds please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue got resolved after setting

```
<java jar="${MXMLC.JAR}" fork="true" failonerror="true">
<jvmarg value="-Xms10m" />
<jvmarg value="-Xmx512m" />
```

Comment: Where did you set that setting?

Answer (score 0):

Add this argument to flex project:

under menu windows-->preferences-->java-->installedJRES ,choose the jdk installed and click on edit button finally add this argument to Field Defalut VM argument: -XX:PermSize=512M -XX:MaxPermSize=1024M

Hope help you